# Xamarin IOS Get Media Artist Images

Tags: ios, xamarin

In Xamarin I am using the following code to retrieve Artist and Genre information from the device music library.

```
        MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMediaQuery mq = new MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMediaQuery ();
        var value = MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int) MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMediaType.Music);
        var type = MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMediaItem.MediaTypeProperty;
        var predicate = MonoTouch.MediaPlayer.MPMediaPropertyPredicate.PredicateWithValue (value, type);
        mq.AddFilterPredicate (predicate);

        foreach (var item in mq.Items) {

            if (item.Artist != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Artist);
            }
            if (item.Genre != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Genre);
            }

        }
```

This works great, but I also need to get the Artist Image. 
In my FOR loop, item only has Artist and Genre available as properties, so thinking I might need to do some other function call. 
I'm finding some of the code around this pretty confusing, so hoping someone could point me in the right direction.